# how to give an action for a button which should have different action for landscape and portrait?

Tags: ios, ios4

in my project , i have  uibutton on a view. when we click on the button an another smallview should load in to the main view with landscape frame different and portrait frame different. any suggestions would helpful to my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the orientation of the device at any time by calling:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

In your code you can check that and setup the desired frame.

Comment: hi drewag, i need to know how can we resize views in different oirientations programatically